# Selenium + C# + Chrome WebDriver: Violation of CSP

Tags: c#, selenium, google-chrome, webdriver

I am running a console application with Selenium based on C# w/ Chrome webdriver.

When I am runnig it without headless option, in the console windows there are no warnings about CSP.

Running with headless option results in this:

```
Refused to connect to 'https://bla.bla/' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive
```

Receiving such a warning every 1-2 secs.

How can I disable CSP in that regard, or filter out those messages?

Answer (score 1):

Solved it with

```
options.AddArgument("log-level=3");
```